# Replacing Special and Unicode Char in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am using PostgreSQL. Data in the table looks like below there is ''. I would like to remove '' with the empty value.

**Query:**

```
select 'Patriots Colony Family Monthly'
```

**Actual Result Screenshot:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

```
Abcd
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex_replace` to remove non alphanumeric chars

```
select regexp_replace(yourColumn, '[^[:alnum:]]', ' ', 'g')
from yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is removing even space in it. I tried to put my string "Abcd Xyz", It is removing space in it and returning "AbcXyz".

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

```
select regexp_replace(yourColumn, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+',' ','g') 
from yourTable;
```